# Block change value of variable when refresh page in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have 2 variables name first and last. When window size is less than 768px, i want first = 1 and last = 5. And when window size is greater than 768px, first = 1 and last = 3. Here is my code.

```
var first = 1;
var last = 5;
window.onresize = function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth 
            || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
            || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

    if (w <= 768){
        first = 1;
        last = 3;
    }

    if (w > 768){
        first = 1;
        last = 5;
    }
}
```

It's worked. But when window size is 600px (less than 768px), i press F5 (refresh), first variable = 1 and last = 5 (these values are changed). I want when i press F5, if window less than 768px, its still 1 and 3. What can i do now? Help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it should be.

So now, we have one Function that set variables as per width of the Window.
We will call it two Times

1. When the page is loaded, you should Set Variables (First,Last) as per Size of window
2. When the page is Resized, you should Set Variables again.

   ```
   var first = 1;
   var last = 5;

   function setVariables()
   {
   var w = window.innerWidth 
           || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
           || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

   if (w <= 768){
       first = 1;
       last = 3;
   }

   if (w > 768){
       first = 1;
       last = 5;
   }
   }

   window.onresize = function(){
   setVariables();
   } 

   setVariables();
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Just move your function into  a separate function and reuse it on page loading:

```
function checkWidth(){
    var w = window.innerWidth 
            || document.documentElement.clientWidth 
            || document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].clientWidth;

    if (w <= 768){
        first = 1;
        last = 3;
    }

    if (w > 768){
        first = 1;
        last = 5;
    }
} 

...

var first = 1;
var last = 5;
window.onresize = checkWidth;
window.onload = checkWidth;
```